SQLite database doesn't work after restarting a discord bot
Literally can't add database for auto roles. I have an auto roles system and people can react/un-react to the "reactions" (numbers) and they will get their roles added or removed. But I need a database because if I restart the bot, i can't react/un-react to the message anymore because it won't give me the role, as excepted.
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is online.")
    #default_file_path = "C:/Python/Steaua Intunecata/av4.gif"    
    #try:
    #    if default_file_path.lower().endswith(('.gif')):
    #        with open(default_file_path, 'rb') as avatar:
    #            await bot.user.edit(avatar=avatar.read())
    #    else:
    #        print("Please provide a valid GIF file path.")
    #except Exception as e:
    #    print(f"Error: {e}")
    change_status.start()
    guild_count = len(bot.guilds)
    bot.db = await aiosqlite.connect("s12220_bank.db")
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    async with bot.db.cursor() as cursor:
        await cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bank (wallet INTEGER, bank INTEGER, maxbank INTEGER, user INTEGER)")
        await cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS suggestions (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, author_id INTEGER, suggestion_text TEXT, status TEXT DEFAULT 'pending')")
    await bot.db.commit()
    print("Connected to database.")
    guild = bot.get_guild(1120312508184530954) 
    category = guild.categories[0]  

    jego = int(1)

    existing_channel = next((c for c in category.voice_channels if c.name.startswith("Members: ")), None)

    if existing_channel and jego == 1:
        await update_member_count(existing_channel, guild)
    #else:
    #    channel = await category.create_voice_channel("Members: 0", position=0)
    #    await update_member_count(channel, guild)

    await guild.chunk()

roles = {
    'premierleague': [1122982318500499589, 1123175761566781461, 1122982042964082708, 1122982862837252197, 1122982423702032436],   
    'laliga': [1122984591028912261, 1122984468580413560, 1122984816862838855, 1238922998996799642, 1122985679291437096, 1122984944529059940],  
    'seriea': [1122987308342325404, 1122985115946070117, 1122987381423878204, 1122985265326202890, 1122987675390066880, 1122987634411704362, 1122987569613910039],  
    'bundesliga': [1122988381006204970, 1122988179247599707, 1122988578763452416, 1122989069668982927, 1122988699815247882],  
    'ligue1': [1122983411510956203, 1122983878269874216, 1122983508428726382, 1122984139944100033, 1122983915255234641],  
    'other': [1122994650760880250, 1121185173480947782, 1121185025262633022, 1121185307203731597, 1121184836485402745, 1121184903325818890, 1121184671485665401, 1121185397087666186, 1122993975708622999]
}

@bot.command()
async def create_roles(ctx):
    embed_premierleague = nextcord.Embed(title="Premier League", color=0x00ff00)
    embed_premierleague.description = "1️⃣ <@&1122982318500499589>\n" \
                                      "2️⃣ <@&1123175761566781461>\n" \
                                      "3️⃣ <@&1122982042964082708>\n" \
                                      "4️⃣ <@&1122982862837252197>\n" \
                                      "5️⃣ <@&1122982423702032436>"

    message = await ctx.send(embed=embed_premierleague)
    await message.add_reaction('1️⃣')
    await message.add_reaction('2️⃣')
    await message.add_reaction('3️⃣')
    await message.add_reaction('4️⃣')
    await message.add_reaction('5️⃣')

    embed_laliga = nextcord.Embed(title="La Liga", color=0x00ff00)
    embed_laliga.description = "1️⃣ <@&1122984591028912261>\n" \
                                "2️⃣ <@&1122984468580413560>\n" \
                                "3️⃣ <@&1122984816862838855>\n" \
                                "4️⃣ <@&1238922998996799642>\n" \
                                "5️⃣ <@&1122985679291437096>\n" \
                                "6️⃣ <@&1122984944529059940>"

    message = await ctx.send(embed=embed_laliga)
    await message.add_reaction('1️⃣')
    await message.add_reaction('2️⃣')
    await message.add_reaction('3️⃣')
    await message.add_reaction('4️⃣')
    await message.add_reaction('5️⃣')
    await message.add_reaction('6️⃣')

    embed_seriea = nextcord.Embed(title="Serie A", color=0x00ff00)
    embed_seriea.description = "1️⃣ <@&1122987308342325404>\n" \
                                "2️⃣ <@&1122987381423878204>\n" \
                                "3️⃣ <@&1122985115946070117>\n" \
                                "4️⃣ <@&1122985265326202890>\n" \
                                "5️⃣ <@&1122987675390066880>\n" \
                                "6️⃣ <@&1122987634411704362>\n" \
                                "7️⃣ <@&1122987569613910039>"

    message = await ctx.send(embed=embed_seriea)
    await message.add_reaction('1️⃣')
    await message.add_reaction('2️⃣')
    await message.add_reaction('3️⃣')
    await message.add_reaction('4️⃣')
    await message.add_reaction('5️⃣')
    await message.add_reaction('6️⃣')
    await message.add_reaction('7️⃣')

    embed_bundesliga = nextcord.Embed(title="Bundesliga", color=0x00ff00)
    embed_bundesliga.description = "1️⃣ <@&1122988381006204970>\n" \
                                    "2️⃣ <@&1122988179247599707>\n" \
                                    "3️⃣ <@&1122988578763452416>\n" \
                                    "4️⃣ <@&1122989069668982927>\n" \
                                    "5️⃣ <@&1122988699815247882>"

    message = await ctx.send(embed=embed_bundesliga)
    await message.add_reaction('1️⃣')
    await message.add_reaction('2️⃣')
    await message.add_reaction('3️⃣')
    await message.add_reaction('4️⃣')
    await message.add_reaction('5️⃣')

    embed_ligue1 = nextcord.Embed(title="Ligue 1", color=0x00ff00)
    embed_ligue1.description = "1️⃣ <@&1122983411510956203>\n" \
                                "2️⃣ <@&1122983878269874216>\n" \
                                "3️⃣ <@&1122983508428726382>\n" \
                                "4️⃣ <@&1122984139944100033>\n" \
                                "5️⃣ <@&1122983915255234641>"

    message = await ctx.send(embed=embed_ligue1)
    await message.add_reaction('1️⃣')
    await message.add_reaction('2️⃣')
    await message.add_reaction('3️⃣')
    await message.add_reaction('4️⃣')
    await message.add_reaction('5️⃣')

    embed_other = nextcord.Embed(title="Other", color=0x00ff00)
    embed_other.description = "1️⃣ <@&1122994650760880250>\n" \
                              "2️⃣ <@&1121185173480947782>\n" \
                              "3️⃣ <@&1121185025262633022>\n" \
                              "4️⃣ <@&1121185307203731597>\n" \
                              "5️⃣ <@&1121184836485402745>\n" \
                              "6️⃣ <@&1121184903325818890>\n" \
                              "7️⃣ <@&1121184671485665401>\n" \
                              "8️⃣ <@&1121185397087666186>\n" \
                              "9️⃣ <@&1122993975708622999>"

    message = await ctx.send(embed=embed_other)
    await message.add_reaction('1️⃣')
    await message.add_reaction('2️⃣')
    await message.add_reaction('3️⃣')
    await message.add_reaction('4️⃣')
    await message.add_reaction('5️⃣')
    await message.add_reaction('6️⃣')
    await message.add_reaction('7️⃣')
    await message.add_reaction('8️⃣')
    await message.add_reaction('9️⃣')

    await ctx.send("Roles have been created!")

@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    guild = reaction.message.guild
    member = guild.get_member(user.id)
    
    if user.bot:
        return

    emoji = str(reaction.emoji)
    roles_dict = {
        'premierleague': {
            '1️⃣': 'Man City',
            '2️⃣': 'Chelsea',
            '3️⃣': 'Liverpool',
            '4️⃣': 'Arsenal',
            '5️⃣': 'ManUnited',
        },
        'laliga': {
            '1️⃣': 'Barcelona',
            '2️⃣': 'Real Madrid',
            '3️⃣': 'Atlético Madrid',
            '4️⃣': 'Villareal',
            '5️⃣': 'Real Sociedad',
            '6️⃣': 'Sevilla',
        },
        'seriea': {
            '1️⃣': 'Napoli',
            '2️⃣': 'Lazio',
            '3️⃣': 'Inter Milan',
            '4️⃣': 'AC Milan',
            '5️⃣': 'Atalanta',
            '6️⃣': 'Roma',
            '7️⃣': 'Juventus',
        },
        'bundesliga': {
            '1️⃣': 'Bayern Munich',
            '2️⃣': 'Borussia Dortmund',
            '3️⃣': 'RB Leipzig',
            '4️⃣': 'Union Berlin',
            '5️⃣': 'Frieburg',
        },
        'ligue1': {
            '1️⃣': 'PSG',
            '2️⃣': 'Lens',
            '3️⃣': 'Marseille',
            '4️⃣': 'Rennes',
            '5️⃣': 'Losc',
        },
        'other': {
            '1️⃣': 'Argentine Primera División',
            '2️⃣': 'Brasileiro Série A',
            '3️⃣': 'Bundesliga',
            '4️⃣': 'Eredivisie',
            '5️⃣': 'Serie A',
            '6️⃣': 'Ligue 1',
            '7️⃣': 'Premier League',
            '8️⃣': 'Saudi League (SPL)',
            '9️⃣': 'Other',
        }
    }

    for league, teams in roles_dict.items():
        if emoji in teams and reaction.message.embeds[0].title.lower().replace(" ", "") == league:
            role_name = teams[emoji]
            role_id = None
            for r_id in roles[league]:
                if role_name.lower() in bot.get_guild(guild.id).get_role(r_id).name.lower():
                    role_id = r_id
                    break
            if role_id is not None:
                await member.add_roles(guild.get_role(role_id))
            else:
                print("Role not found.")
                pass

@bot.event
async def on_reaction_remove(reaction, user):
    guild = reaction.message.guild
    member = guild.get_member(user.id)
    
    if user.bot:
        return

    emoji = str(reaction.emoji)
    roles_dict = {
        'premierleague': {
            '1️⃣': 'Man City',
            '2️⃣': 'Chelsea',
            '3️⃣': 'Liverpool',
            '4️⃣': 'Arsenal',
            '5️⃣': 'ManUnited',
        },
        'laliga': {
            '1️⃣': 'Barcelona',
            '2️⃣': 'Real Madrid',
            '3️⃣': 'Atlético Madrid',
            '4️⃣': 'Villareal',
            '5️⃣': 'Real Sociedad',
            '6️⃣': 'Sevilla',
        },
        'seriea': {
            '1️⃣': 'Napoli',
            '2️⃣': 'Lazio',
            '3️⃣': 'Inter Milan',
            '4️⃣': 'AC Milan',
            '5️⃣': 'Atalanta',
            '6️⃣': 'Roma',
            '7️⃣': 'Juventus',
        },
        'bundesliga': {
            '1️⃣': 'Bayern Munich',
            '2️⃣': 'Borussia Dortmund',
            '3️⃣': 'RB Leipzig',
            '4️⃣': 'Union Berlin',
            '5️⃣': 'Frieburg',
        },
        'ligue1': {
            '1️⃣': 'PSG',
            '2️⃣': 'Lens',
            '3️⃣': 'Marseille',
            '4️⃣': 'Rennes',
            '5️⃣': 'Losc',
        },
        'other': {
            '1️⃣': 'Argentine Primera División',
            '2️⃣': 'Brasileiro Série A',
            '3️⃣': 'Bundesliga',
            '4️⃣': 'Eredivisie',
            '5️⃣': 'Serie A',
            '6️⃣': 'Ligue 1',
            '7️⃣': 'Premier League',
            '8️⃣': 'Saudi League (SPL)',
            '9️⃣': 'Other',
        }
    }

    for league, teams in roles_dict.items():
        if emoji in teams and reaction.message.embeds[0].title.lower().replace(" ", "") == league:
            role_name = teams[emoji]
            role_id = None
            for r_id in roles[league]:
                if role_name.lower() in bot.get_guild(guild.id).get_role(r_id).name.lower():
                    role_id = r_id
                    break
            if role_id is not None:
                await member.remove_roles(guild.get_role(role_id))
            else:
                print("Role not found.")
                pass

I've literally tried absolutely everything i could think of. I'm not the best when it comes to python, but i know a thing or two surely. Literally anything, the most i did to this is add a working database that actually updated when i reacted, but when i turned the bot off and then i turned it back on again it still wouldn't work if i reacted to the same message. Honestly, absolutely ANY advice is welcome, i feel like i'm about to throw my pc out the window. I don't even need you guys to give me the whole code, even a snippet is good enough. literally everything
